# How do I knock back my player when they shoot?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add knockback to my entire player when it shoots, so it can impulse itself.

I'm new to making games, I don't know much about c# and I haven't found any tutorials for the thing I need

Comment: I see theres been downvotes and votes to close on this question. Perhaps take a look at this checklist https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know what you need help on here. But try to I'll answer the question.

When your player fires their gun, you would typically create a new object and apply a force to it for slow move projectiles or alternatively, you'll do a ray trace to see if the target is hit for laser beam style shots.

To make the player move, use AddForce on their Rigid Body to apply a force in the opposite direction. That direction is simply the negative direction of the projectile's direction (or the ray that was traced)